# Adding a new field on my product pages for shippingDetails

Tags: google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I am in the process of adding the `shippingDetails` field (`deliveryTime` & `transitTime`) to my product pages to increase their visibility in search results by enabling the display of additional product snippets. The same information is also required by the new `ProductVariant` Structured Data.

```js
"deliveryTime": {
            "@type": "ShippingDeliveryTime",
            "handlingTime": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "minValue": 0,
              "maxValue": 1,
              "unitCode": "DAY"
            },
            "transitTime": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "minValue": 1,
              "maxValue": 5,
              "unitCode": "DAY"
```

My challenge is that marketplace products have both values available, while for our own products I only have `deliveryTime`, as an aggregated value which already include `leadtimetoShip`.

Any advise/idea on which data source to use?

I am stuck in understanding which data source to provide here.